# Should I invoke a separate goroutine for any async operation?

Tags: mysql, go, asynchronous, goroutine, go-gorm

I have just started with Go with a background in NodeJS. I wrote the following program that opens the connection with the database, queries the database table and prints the record.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username string
    Password string
}



func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql","root:1234@(localhost)/database_test")
    db.LogMode(true)
    defer db.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect to the database")
    }

    var users []User
    db.Table("user").Find(&users)
    fmt.Println("after finding the user")
    fmt.Println("user ", users)
}
```

The code works fine. But I want to understand this, doesn't this program block the main thread? Should I be doing any async operation like the database call made inside `main` in a separate goroutine?

I have been using `Promises` with NodeJS so it feels a little different with Go.

***EDIT: After adding goroutine in the main method***

The following code invokes a separate goroutine to query the database. But does not it still block the main thread in that it is waiting for the response from the channel? If yes, is there a better to do this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username string
    Password string
}

func dbRead(db *gorm.DB) <-chan []User {
    c := make(chan []User)
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("starting the go routine to find the users")
        defer close(c)
        var users []User
        db.Table("user").Find(&users)
        c <- users
    }()

    return c
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql","root:1234@(localhost)/database_test")
    db.LogMode(true)
    defer db.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect to the database")
    }

    userList := <-dbRead(db)
    fmt.Println("user ", userList)
}
```

Comment: It largely depends on what you want to achieve in your program. In this case main will block indeed, but depending on what else you want to do in main you may or may not want to go for goroutines. If you go with goroutines, you'll most likely end up using channels for data exchange between methods.

Comment: @favoretti Have updated my question by adding a go-routine and receiving the response from the channel. But the question still remains the same? Looks like until I receive the response from the channel main thread will remain blocked?

Comment: I guess this is purely academic for now. To unblock main you would need to consume messages from your channel in yet another goroutine :)

Comment: That said, main should wait for goroutines to finish working, if you exit main while firing off uncontrolled goroutines, main will just exit without waiting for them to finish. Check out https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups

Comment: You'll know when to use goroutines. Until then keep it simple. There is no point at all in emulation what nodejs does just for the heck of it. Go is a very different language.

Comment: You need to block main or your program doesn't do anything, otherwise it just would just initialize and exit. Make as little as possible concurrent -- it's far simpler to understand what's going on.